# Recieving an Attribute error when trying to add a new view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

Im learning django, and following a tutorial online, im trying to create a new view for "home" but i keep recieving an attribute error. `AttributeError: module 'pages.views' has no attribute 'home'`
Ive checked that I'm not doing anything wrong, and so I thought maybe the tutorial is outdated etc, but in the urls.py file, it says to do the exact same thing.

Ive searched around google and tried removing spaces before the comas, changing the import name to a ".", Ive tried changing the name of the function and in the urls.

views.py:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```

urls.py:

```py
"""trydjango URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

I want to change the home view to just say "hello world" but its returning the attribute error, if i remove the "path('', views.home, name='home')," it works fine (with the default home page)

Comment: perhaps... did you save `views.py` file?

Comment: if you can share the path of `views.py` and `urls.py`, it can be disorganized easily. the issue is something related to the path. Just check `home` is at `/pages/views.py` and `urlpatterns` is at  `/trydjango/urls.py` where `/` points to the folder containing `manage.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing a wrong path of **views.py**.

Try this :

```
"""trydjango URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views    #Import views file from your current root directory

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Sorry I didn't check, but hope this works. Apologies if it doesn't help your case.

Answer (score 0):

A view in django is a callable that receives a request and return a response. 
So, I think you should add a parameter request to your view.

Try this:

```
def home(request,*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```